# Is it wise to create a pojo which inherit from a class and has dependency(object) of the same class?

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I saw someone writing a POJO class similar to as below:

```
class A{
    someVariables...
}
class B extends A{
    A a = new A();
    someVariables...
}
```

I am pretty convinced that this is not a wise way to create a class because it will cause the data integrity problem(both variable inherited and of object 'A' can have different values) when both variables are intended to store same value. Each time if someone updates any variable he has to update it at two places. I would appreciate is someone can enlighten me on this and tell me where it can be wise to create such class...Pros and cons will work.

Comment: Could you share some real code? It is unclear what exactly is duplicated between these classes.

Comment: I suppose person who wrote it misunderstood [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle

Comment: It depends on the usecase. There might be cases where the inner `A` is not meant to be the same as the outer `B` (even if this is an `A`) or `B` is meant to be a proxy/decorator that isn't meant to hold any values (in which case `A` should probably be an interface but that's not always possible - CDI and EJB are cases where such proxies are generated).

Comment: from modeling PoV: **class B IS class A** and **HAS class A**. Could be counter-intuitive, but occasionally there are generic, recursive constructs like these e.g. a graph where each node could store some data, but also a node itself.

Comment: @MickMnemonic No, I cannot share any code. I saw someone writing such code.

Comment: Okay, then, what do you mean with `both variables are intended to store same value`? Why would they be intended to store the same value -- how is this POJO used?

Comment: @diginoise Good point but in my situation both inherited variables and object 'A' stores same values.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Both the inherited variables as well as the object of 'A' in 'B' stores the same data. I am also not clear what's the intent of such class, thats why I asked for pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to provide complete class code. But I think it's the decorator design pattern. Decorator design pattern is extensively used in most Java IO classes and it's a kind of modifying functionality at runtime for objects. 
For more information about it, check the page [Decorator Design Pattern in Java Example](https://www.journaldev.com/1540/decorator-design-pattern-in-java-example)